# Minimal value from set if expression

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is it possible to get min value from set, but only if that value is bigger than other value?

Example:

```
A1 = 2500
A2 = 4800
B6 = 1200

D1 = 2000
```

I want to get min from A1, A2, B6 but only if that value is bigger than D1, so here result should be 2500.
I have tried with min(if()) but to use it I need to have values in continous range.

I think it is possible with VBA, but I would like to do that with formulas.

Comment: And if D1 is less that any of numbers - what's then?

Comment: same - min but bigger than D1, so 1200 in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of examples of pseudo `MINIF` formulas but your non-contiguous range of cells will demand that at least two ranges be looked at individually with then their results compared. `MIN` can take many parameters.

`=MIN(INDEX((A1:A2)+(A1:A2<D1)*1E+99,,),B6+(B6<D1)*1E+99)`

Any value in the disjointed range that is less than the value in D1 has 1E+99 added to it and that won't be the `MIN` of anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If** your range were contiguous (which actually makes sense here IMHO), that would look like this:

[image]